# Connect Activemq using iiop

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I am successfully sending/receiving messages to ActiveMQ using TCP brokerURL as: `tcp://localhost:61616`

How can I sending/receiving messages to ActiveMQ using **IIOP**?

Comment: Why do you want to use IIOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot. Java IIOP is not supported by Apache ActiveMQ.

The TCP protocol is using a custom binary protocol named `openwire` which is ActiveMQ specific. ActiveMQ is a multi protocol broker, so you can also use AMQP, MQTT, stomp etc. But IIOP / Corba is not supported.